# Using Camel Bindy in Has-A relationship

Tags: java, apache-camel

Hi I have a problem with exporting java Object to CSV file in Camel. Suppose if i have a java object namely Student,

```
@CsvRecord(separator=",")
public class Student {  
    @DataField(pos=1)
    private String name;
    @DataField(pos=2)
    private String college;

    // getters and setters
}
```

I will export this object into a csv file using below code in camel route,

```
.marshal(new BindyCsvDataFormat(camel.demo.Book.class))
.to("file:data/destination?fileName=book.csv")
```

But what if i have a one more entity Object named Address in Student object. And i want to print particular values of Address along with remaing student details in my csv.

```
@CsvRecord(separator=",")
public class Student {  
    @DataField(pos=1)
    private String name;
    @DataField(pos=2)
    private String college;

    private Address address;

    // getters and setters
}

public class Address {  
    private int houseNo;
    private String street;
    private String city;

    //getters and setters
}
```

NOw i want to save Student details (name,college) and only (city) from Address in csv. Can someone please help me to achieve this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `@Link` annotation as described [here](http://camel.apache.org/bindy.html):

```
@CsvRecord(separator=",")
public class Student {  
    @DataField(pos=1)
    private String name;

    @DataField(pos=2)
    private String college;

    @Link
    private Address address;
...
}
```

And for the class `Address`:

```
@Link
public class Address {  
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @peter. Its working. I have one more doubt what if i replace address object with List of Address. Anyways i will be looking into the documentation. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah i got it Peter. It's @OneToMany annotation i have to use.